# Error after runing cargo run I got error: could not compile `wayland-protocols`

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, vagrant, rust-cargo

```
error: could not compile `wayland-protocols`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name wayland_protocols --edition=2018 /home/vagrant/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wayland-protocols-0.28.6/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 --cfg 'feature="client"' --cfg 'feature="unstable_protocols"' --cfg 'feature="wayland-client"' -C metadata=7617ec321c2b5731 -C extra-filename=-7617ec321c2b5731 --out-dir /vagrant/target/debug/deps -L dependency=/vagrant/target/debug/deps --extern bitflags=/vagrant/target/debug/deps/libbitflags-05dfd5b5d1225bed.rmeta --extern wayland_client=/vagrant/target/debug/deps/libwayland_client-5f1145fb2f59d147.rmeta --extern wayland_commons=/vagrant/target/debug/deps/libwayland_commons-29ab383d18290005.rmeta --cap-lints allow` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from someone on Twitter. What happened is that `rustc` didn’t have enough memory to compile my project, and so the OS killed it (OOM).

I added more memory in my `Vagrantfile` and reloaded vagrant. Now it works!

Here is a link to the tweet: https://twitter.com/dcodefrenzy/status/1478730150078566403?s=20

Comment: Can you offer a link to the associated Tweet to ensure the person who helped you is acknowledged?